# What does this mean in javascript: var obj = (function(){ .... })()

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

Please, can someone explain to me what does that mean in JS:

```
var obj = (function(){ 
   // code
})()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an anonymous function that is immediately executed. It's return value is assigned to `obj`. For example:

```
var obj = (function () {
    return 10;
}()); //Notice that calling parentheses can go inside or outside the others

console.log(obj); //10
```

They are often used to introduce a new scope so you don't clutter the scope the code is executing in:

```
var obj = (function () {
    var something = 10; //Not available outside this anonymous function
    return something;
}());

console.log(obj); //10
```

Note that since this is a function *expression*, and not a function *declaration*, it should have a semi-colon after the closing curly brace.

Answer (score 5):

It's called an immediately instantiated function. It runs the function, and the returned value is assigned to `obj`. You can create a scope or class with it, in which you can use closures to keep certain variables private within that scope. See John Resigs [page](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/) on that subject.

So, if the function looks like this:

```
var obj = (function(n){
  return 2+n;
})(3);
```

The value of `obj` would be 5.